# Receive parameters in action controller JSON

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

In ASP.NET MVC 5 with Entity Framework 6, I'm using a typical MVC Controller template with EF and I'm adding a custom action there.

My idea is to call this action from an AJAX call, to dynamically populate a select2 dropdown.

```
...
    public JsonResult getWarrehouses(string name)
            {
                var warrehouses = from c in db.warrehouses 
                              where c.nom_wrh.Contains(name)
                              orderby c.nom_wrh
                              select new { c.cod_wrh, c.nom_wrh} ;
                return Json(warrehouses.ToList(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
...
```

However, I don't know how to pass parameters to this, the parameter provided is always null. If I type: http://localhost:[port]/warrehouses/getWarrehouses/somestring the parameter is not received.
How I suppose to declare that action in order to receive GET parameters?
Feel free to provide an alternate solution if my approach is wrong.

Comment: If you are using MVC in ASP.NET then ad the params to your routes file and it should pass the matched values to the method called.

Comment: Try using http://localhost:[port]/warrehouses/getWarrehouses?name=somestring

Comment: The problem was the way I was calling. Thanks.

Comment: Either change the parameter to `string id` (i.e use the default route) or add a specific route to your route definitions - `url: warrehouese/getWarrehouses/{name}`

Answer (score 2):

The problem may be in the calling. For example:
the "**name**" is the name of your parameter on your Action;

```
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: @Url.Action("getWarrehouses"),
            data: {
                name: VALUE_TO_PASS

            },
            success: function (data) {

             // Manipulate (data)
            }
```

Comment: Perhaps I should change that POST for a GET :)

Answer (score 0):

you need to use browser extensions like postman https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman/fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop?hl=en

they help you to make a get/post requests to getWarrehouses . with your parameters